# Why byte[] turns into String?

Tags: java, types

I have this piece of Java code:

```java
public class MapJSONHandler<KeyType, ValueType> {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private String filePath;

    public MapJSONHandler(String filePath) {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public ValueType getValue(KeyType key) throws Exception{
        ValueType value = getMap().get(key);
        return value;
    }

    private Map<KeyType, ValueType> getMap() throws Exception {
        Map<KeyType, ValueType> map;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.length() == 0) {
            map = new HashMap<>();
        } else {
            map = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>>() {});
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Program1
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        MapJSONHandler<String, byte[]> usersHandler = new MapJSONHandler<>("users.json");
        byte[] hash = usersHandler.getValue("foo");
    }
}
```

JSON file contains proper element. Program1 is throwing ClassCastException (java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B). Why?

Comment: Why do you convert json's content into byte[] ?

Comment: I save password hashes and RSA keys in json, it's easier for me to handle it as byte[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *false expectation* here.
And that is about the properties' values being retrieved in the form of `byte[]` just because you defined a *generic-enabled* class

```
class MapJSONHandler<KeyType, ValueType>
```

---

This is, unfortunately, untrue. With this line of code

```
mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>>() {})
```

`ObjectMapper#readValue` will return a `HashMap<Object, Object>`, because the generic types get lost.
You can see the knowledge of `<String, byte[]>` is no more here.

[image]

And you can notice the difference compared to explicitly setting the types using

```
 new TypeReference<HashMap<String, byte[]>>() {}
```

[image]

---

The underlying values will then be of any allowed type, such as `String`, `Integer`, `Double` or `Boolean`. Thus

```
usersHandler.getValue("foo")
```

will return, rightfully, a `String`, and not a `byte[]`.

---

If you need to convert all the values to `byte[]`, you need a custom de-serializer, I think, or, just to explicitly set the generic types.